# Tracking a users position and showing it on the map for all other users - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, tracking

I was searching for hours, but I can't find an answer on this topic. I have managed to set up an application which shows my position, tracks it and updates my marker whenever my position changes.

I would like to do the same for all other users (for finding friends), but I don't understand the right way this has to be done.

Should I upload each users Lat and Lng to a server, then downloading it while placing markers on the map? This way I may not get fast location updates, or does the Google Map Api contain some tools to achieve this in the right way?

I would really appreciate some help.
E.

UPDATE

After doing some more resources, I realised that an online database is the way to go for this task.
Steps I made to read save and retrieve users positions:

- Create an online (mysql) database
- in my android project I have implemented: GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener. But most important is **LocationListener** - to receive the current location coordinates each time the user changes position.
- I then uploaded the coordinates using the HttpUrlConnection via POST method, and adding them to the database using php.
- back in the app I create a new instance of the GoogleMap class, and the same way as I have uploaded I download all other users coordinates via HttpUrlConnection, iterate over the JSON response and placing markers on the map in the same time.

Everything works like it should, there may be other ways but I think this is the most straight forward solution. Hope this small guide will help.

Comment: +1,I also tried to find    an answer to this problem with no result.. google has no tutorial for this nor documentations....

Comment: thanks for the update! it'll help a lot. In your opinion is there a way to retrieve users credentials(eg. name,mobile phone, etc, after finding him near my location?

Comment: @oIrC - Of course. The same way as you upload the coordinates for each user, you can include the credentials as well. First you will need to promt the user to enter the desired information into, let say, a EditText field, the you get the values and pass them to the server together with the coordinates. You can do all of this using a library called [Loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) a nice Async http client, they have a great documentation